# Need function to find largest value in an array, return it to main( ) and print out

Tags: c

To me, my program looks like it should do what I want it to do: prompt a user to enter 10 values for an array, then find the largest of those values in the array using a function, then return the largest number to the main () function and print it out.

But, when I enter values, I never get numbers back that look anything like the ones I'm entering.

For example, let's say I enter just "10, 11" I get back "1606416648 = largest value".

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIMIT 10
int largest(int pointer[]); 
int main(void)
{

int str[LIMIT];
int max;
int i = 0;

printf("Please enter 10 integer values:\n");
while (i < LIMIT)
{
    scanf("%d", &str[i]);
    i++;
}
// Thanks for your help, I've been able to make the program work with the above edit!
max = largest(str);
printf("%d = largest value\n", max);

return 0;
}

int largest(int pointer[])

{
int i;
int max = pointer[0];

for (i = 1; i < LIMIT; i++)
{
   if (max < pointer[i])
        max = pointer[i];
}
return max;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your updated code. Please also explain what happens when you compile and run it.

Comment: OK, i just explained in the code above: "When I compile and run it, I don't get the largest value back; I get a random number"

Comment: See the edit to my answer for more suggestions of how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Code-Guru, it now works! I must say, I don't remember learning this particular loop construction for use with arrays, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("Please enter 10 integer values:\n");
scanf("%d", &str[LIMIT]);`

This doesn't do what you think.  First, it only reads one number in.  Second, you are reading it into the last position + 1 of the array.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. Any suggestions on how I get it to do what I want? I tried &str[0] but that didn't work either...

Comment: You need to do scanf in a loop, from 0 to LIMIT-1.

Comment: is this close?     printf("Please enter 10 integer values:\n");
    while (i < LIMIT && scanf("%d", &*str))
    {
        str[i];
        i++;
    }

Comment: Close; ou probably want to reference the array position in your scanf (`str[i]`)...

Comment: I changed it to a loop as you can see above. However, this is what I get when I enter numbers: Please enter 10 integer values:
1, 2, 3
32767 = largest value

Comment: You have to enter one number at a time, pressing `enter` after each one

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &str[LIMIT]);` reads in one number and puts it in the memory location one past the end of your array.

**After changes:**

1. You don't need `scanf()` in your while condition; it should go in the `while` body instead.
2. Your `scanf()` still isn't quite right. You need to tell it *where* in the array you want to store the input.
3. `str[i];` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I took out the [LIMIT] part, but I still get strange large numbers... What am I supposed to put there?

Comment: You need to read the values one at a time, kind of like you do to find the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks, Code Guru... Why doesn't this work:              printf("Please enter 10 integer values:\n");
    while (i < LIMIT && scanf("%d", str))
    {
        str[i];
        i++;
    }

Comment: @user1992348 Please edit your original post with your new code and explain what happens when you compile and run it.

Comment: OK, i just updated the original post with the new code, but I still can't get the program to work like it should